# Adding 'show in explorer' to the phpstorm menu

Tags: menu, user-experience, phpstorm, right-click

When right clicking on a folder/file in the project explorer I get an option to `show in explorer`

[image]

However when right clicking inside the file or the code view I do not get this option.

[image]

Is there a way to add this to the menu?

Comment: **Use keyboard -- it's faster:** `Alt+F1, 8` or `(Navigate | Select In .. | Show in Explorer)`. As for **Editor context menu** -- it's not there -- you have to add it there yourself (`Settings | Menus and Toolbars`). **Alternatively:** just assign custom shortcut to that action (Settings | Keymap -- search for "Show" -- it will be on the very bottom, called "Show/Reveal in Explorer...."

Comment: man, amazing :) add that as an answer please :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Editor context menu:** you have to add it there yourself -- `Settings | Menus and Toolsbars | Editor Popup Menu`

On another though: **use keyboard -- it's faster**: <kbd>Alt+F1, 8</kbd> or `View | Select In... | Show In Explorer`.

**Alternatively:** assign custom shortcut to that specific action at `Settings | Keymap` -- search by "show" word -- the action will be listed at the very end of the matched list: "Show/Revel in Explorer..."

Answer (score 2):

Edit the context menu:

**File** | **Settings** (Alt + F7) | **Menus and Toolbars** | **Editor Popup Menu**

Choose the first item (Spelling), click the button **Add After...** and then choose the command: **Other** | **Show In Explorer**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add a shortcut key to open Explorer. (i try this in Ubuntu)

1. Add an external tool (Settings -> Tools -> External Tools)
   add tool under that
   [[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18sbw.png)]
   Program : nautilus
   Parameters: $FilePath$
2. Add this in Keymap (settings -> keymap)
   Under [External Tools] you will find your new tool.
   Just add a keyboard shortcut. e.g. F10

Thats it.